# Loop with odd sequence

Tags: freemarker

How to write loop with odd sequence in Apache FreeMarker template?

for example:

```
<#list seq as n>
    ...?
   ${n_index}
</#list>
```

As result: 1,3,4,5..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Modulus](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_arit) operator.

```
<#list seq as n>
   <#if n % 2 == 1>
       <#-- your code here -->
   </#if>

</#list>
```

Comment: But what's `x` in your example? Anyway, there's `n?is_odd_item` now; see my answer.

Comment: @ddekany indeed, it's n, fixed

Comment: Assuming it's `n` that need to be checked, not its position in the sequence... I'm not sure as the OP has written `${n_index}`, not `${n}`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually want to print the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc. item of the sequence, as opposed to filter by the parity of the list item (`n`) itself...
If the result is 1, 2, etc., then either you actually want the even items, or you want `n?counter` that is 1-based, not `n?index` that is 0-based. Assuming the last (plus I also print the item itself):

```
<#list seq as n>
   <#if n?is_odd_item>
      ${n?counter}: ${n}
   </#if>
</#list>
```

Related page in the manual: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_loop_var.html